# Selecting certain sections of a XML file

Tags: c#, xml

Hi i have a C# windows form that has two list boxes on it. The left one contains a list of 16 student module codes that are available to enroll onto. The user selects a module from the left to transfer to the right box. I have it working up to this point, the module code transfers when the select button is clicked.

Once a module has been transfered I need to click on it and print out onto a label (placed to the right of it) the full module details that are held in an XML file.

I am able to read through the contents of the XML file and output that to the label (all contents). What I need it to do is just print out the "SELECTED module" details to the label. So I have to somehow read through the XML file and pick out the particular module/modules that the user selects? So if he/she selects 8 modules then I just want the details of all of those to display on the label?

Comment: The XML snippet will help a lot here. You can use an xpath expression to select certain node in you XML data.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the documentation for System.Xml.XmlDocument or System.Xml.Linq.XDocument on MSDN.
If your course is an XML elementm your code might look like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();            
        doc.Load(stream); // you can load it from stream, textreader or use LoadXml to init it from string
        XmlNodeList courseNodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/rootelement/courseelement"); // provide a valid Xpath here
        //work with courseNodes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedNodes = doc.Descendants("node")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("type") == "selected1" || (string)x.Attribute("type") == "selected2" || etc...)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq to Xml.
Here is a small sample

```
        private const string modulesXml =
        "<modules><module id =\"m1\">data1</module><module id =\"m2\">data2</module><module id =\"m3\">data3</module></modules>";

    public string GetModule(string id)
    {
        var modules = XDocument.Parse(modulesXml);
        return modules.Descendants("module").First(n => n.Attribute("id").Value == id).Value;
    }
```